# Dynamically deserialize a JSON to acces its generic type

Tags: c#, reflection, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an configuration-JSON dynamically to an object.

The JSON is a combination of a base and a custom for each service I want to configure.

one config looks like

```
{
    "_clr": "MyNamespace.Models.Admin.MailServiceConfig, Assembly",
    "configuration": {
        "mailWarning": 120
    }

}
```

the only thing what changes is the content of "configuration" (another service has another configuration with more properties with more levels)

So the classes for deserializing would look like this:

```cs
public class ServiceConfiguration
{
    [JsonProperty("_clr")]
    public string Clr { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public IServiceValidation Configuration { get; set; }
}

public interface IServiceValidation
{
    bool ThrowError();
}

public class ExtraConfiguration<T>: ServiceConfiguration where T: IServiceValidation
{
    [JsonProperty("configuration")]
    public new T Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

My target is to deserialize to `ServiceConfiguration` to get `Clr` - with this info I would deserialize a second time to `ServiceConfiguration<[Clr]>`.

I wrote the method for this:

```
private ServiceConfiguration _getConfiguration(string configuration)
{
    ServiceConfiguration config = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceConfiguration>(configuration);
    string className = config.Clr; // classname must be "Namespace.MyClass, MyAssembly"

    Type baseType = typeof(ExtraConfiguration<>);
    Type[] typeArgs = {Type.GetType(className)};

    Type genericType = baseType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

    return (ServiceConfiguration)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(configuration, genericType);
}
```

This returns the casted object - the problem is, I want to access the property `Configuration` which is now `T` as `IServiceValidation` to execute `ThrowError()`. But when I try to access, `Configuration` is null.

When debugging, I can see, there are now two `Configuration`-Properties. One is `null` and one has the object I want - any idea how I can access the second one as `IServiceValidation`?[image]

Comment: do you need is the value of `mailWarning` ?

Comment: `mailWarning` is a Property that is getting checked in the implemented `ThrowError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach.
Fetch the type from the json, fetch the config json from the original json and create the dynamic service validator from it.

```
var configuration = @"{
                ""_clr"": ""Playground.MailServiceConfig, Playground"",
                ""configuration"": {
                        ""mailWarning"": 120
                }
            }";

var configurationJson = JObject.Parse(configuration);
var type = Type.GetType(configurationJson["_clr"].Value<string>());
var config = configurationJson["configuration"] as JObject;
var serviceValidation = config.ToObject(type) as IServiceValidation;
```